# bootstrap CSS issue on Click Trigger Space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="round" style="position: absolute; top: 40%; right: -13px;" id="adduser">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="font-size: 1.2em; cursor: pointer;"></span>
</div>
<div class="round" style="position: absolute; top: 55%; right: -14px;" id="removeuser">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="font-size: 1.2em; cursor: pointer;"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

You can see the above on id of adduser and removeuser. My issue is that the "click space" shown in the image doesn't feel natural. When I select adduser, it has to be in the blue-zone of glyphicon or otherwise it won't fire. You can put cursor inside the circle, but not on the glyphicon... which poses a problem. It is as expected but how do I make it so the blue-zone is larger or the exact circle as the "round" class for natural selection?

Please advise!

EDIT:

```
.round {
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Forgot that I had css on round.

Comment: Anchor tag with display block?

Comment: I tried moving the adduser to another div with display block. <div style="display:block" id="adduser"> but that doesn't do anything.. or maybe I built it wrong?

Comment: Can you provide us with a bit more code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sure. On top of that I just use <script> $('#adduser').click(function() { console.log('fired'); ... }</script>.

Comment: I mean, like the CSS for the class round etc

Comment: Oh.. its from bootstrap, default from there. I'll find how it was defined in the bootstrap css... need a few. Nvm I defined it and I forgot. 
.round {
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: And just to be sure.. `#removeuser` & `#adduser` don't have any styling rules?

Comment: Just checked, they don't.

Comment: I am open to other methods to build a vertical line with left/right buttons in the middle like above... opened a post about that but no response :S..